# Does "previous Thursday" refer to the the last Thursday that passed or the one before that?

Tags: meaning

I am emailing an interview follow up for a position that I didn't hear back from. I had a group interview on Tuesday (9/22/15) and a phone interview on Thursday (9/24/15). I sent a thank you letter for the group interview and am typing my follow up email. Here is my first sentence:

> Thanks for speaking with me the previous Thursday about the [position]
>   at [company].

Does "previous Thursday" in this context mean Thursday (9/25/15) or Thursday (10/1/15)? If the latter, what would work when referring to Thursday (9/25/15)?

Comment: Best advice is you need to write the date, rather than the day. 9/25 sits too far away!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to say is that 25 Sept was a Friday! So I assume you mean the 24th.

You cannot use 'previous' in this context. 'Previous' is a relative term, and has to be 'previous' to something. And unless you state that something it is meaningless. E.g. *I saw him on Saturday 14th November last year. I remember the date because on the previous Thursday I had been involved in an accident*

The expression which will work for you is  ***the Thursday before last***. But for clarity's sake I would always say *Thank you for speaking to me on Thursday 24th*.

Answer (score 1):

“The previous Thursday” refers to the latest Thursday before some temporal point of reference. When the temporal point of reference is the present moment, or the time of e-mailing, it is more usual to say simply “last Thursday.” For the Thursday before last Thursday, we may say “Thursday before last,” but at that point it is almost easier just to use the exact date.

As to whether “‘previous Thursday’ in this context” means 9/24 or 10/1, there is not enough context shown us to say. How it would be interpreted by the recipient of your e-mail is hard to predict, depending as it does on what temporal point of reference floats uppermost in the recipient’s mind. The simple solution would be to say something like “Thanks for speaking with me on 24 September.”